# MySQL - store data as json in one column or in separate columns

Tags: mysql, json

I am creating a page using PHP and MySQL that displays the opening times of various shops.

The data is coming from another site through an API. At the moment there is a cron script which copies shop information to a local database which makes it faster when displaying the data.

My plan is to add the opening times to this cron task and store them in the local database. Would it be better practice to add 7 columns to the database for each day of the week or have one column and add the opening times as a json encoded string?

Comment: The json idea is good practice and you could do what ever you want with json formatted data.

Comment: I think stored json encoded data will limit your project in the future. For example, how would you query your db to find shops opened in a specified time frame?

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the most optimal way to store data depends on how you will query it.

Using JSON makes it easy to store all the days of the week in one JSON structure, but it makes it hard to do any searches (as andrew commented above). It depends which of these tasks is more important for your application.

Using seven columns makes it easy to search for the opening time for a specific day, but harder to search for the opening time across all seven days. Or find the day of the week with the earliest opening time. Or sum up the number of hours open per week.

I would store it as a separate table, with one row per day of the week per shop:

```
CREATE TABLE ShopOpen (
  shop_id INT NOT NULL,
  day_of_week TINYINT NOT NULL,
  open_start TIME NOT NULL,
  open_end TIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (shop_id, day_of_week)
);
```